# php and mysql installation issues on windows 2003 server - IIS6

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to install Oscommerce which requires mysql and php. I already have PHP set up and I have installed Mysql but when i run php phpinfo() i get the following error.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>php phpinfo()
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
```

Does anyone know why i am getting these errors? I've already configured the php.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the thread safe version of PHP but the MySQL module you are using is not thread safe. Try installing the thread safe version of the MySQL PHP module.

If you can, try not using Windows. Most of the software you are trying to run was originally written for unix type OSes. Everything would run quite smoothly.

That being said, I am running PHP on a Windows server to get data out of the SQL Server db. When installing this, I used a service from Microsoft. I think it was this:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

MySQL database drivers were included.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing a complete reinstall of the binaries zip from http://windows.php.net/download/ and it all worked fine.